# Hibernate - mapping a class more than once

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to add a persist a newly added class.  When I started there was a class named `Tournament` with a member of type `Schedule` which simply wraps a list of `Session` objects. This is the hibernate mapping for the class. It's id and other fields have been omitted.

```
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
  <class name="fully.qualified.class.Tournament" table="tournaments">
    <component name="schedule" class="fully.qualified.class.Schedule">
      <list name="sessions" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true" table="tournament_sessions" >
        <key column="tournament_id" not-null="true"/>
        <index column="session_index"/>
        <one-to-many class="fully.qualified.class.Session"/>
      </list>
    </component>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now I need to create a new class `OtherThing` that also has a `Schedule.` So I duplicated the session table and called it `other_thing_sessions.` I also created a hibernate mapping that looks very similar to the one above:

```
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
  <class name="fully.qualified.class.OtherThing" table="other_things">
    <component name="schedule" class="fully.qualified.class.Schedule">
      <list name="sessions" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true" table="other_thing_sessions" >
        <key column="other_thing_id" not-null="true"/>
        <index column="session_index"/>
        <one-to-many class="fully.qualified.class.Session"/>
      </list>
    </component>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

To my surprise this resulted in the following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: fully.qualified.class.Session column: session_index (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

It seems like hibernate doesn't like me using this class repeatedly so I tried adding the attribute `entity-name="OtherThingSession"` to the one-to-many element. Now I've got this error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: OtherThingSession
```

This threw me off for a minute, so I went back and looked at my original error. I decided to just change the name of the index column in the new mapping. This didn't get a complaint from hibernate, but persisting didn't work. It seems like it tried inserting the session object into the `tournament_sessions` table when I was trying to persist a `OtherThing.`

Anyone have any ideas of how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't map a class twice. Hibernate can't handle this. You'll get strange errors than, as you've seen. (Also the first level cache does not work correctly when a class is mapped twice, because Hibernate uses the class to decide to which table a cached instance belongs to. I had the effect to get two instances (and so an exception) on uniqueResult() thought in the table there was only one.)

What you can do:

Create two "empty" class which extend Session without adding any functionality to it, for example

```
public class TournamentSession extends Session {}

public class OtherSession extends Session {}
```

Then in the one `<one-to-many>` attribute you use `TournamentSession`, in the other you use `OtherSession`. `Session` itself never must be mapped nor be used in a Hibernate attribute.